# npm dependencies error while updating or installing npm on old project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

There is this very old project i am trying to run, whenever i try to npm install or start the project it gives of various dependencies error especially errors of outdated npm version, i have the latest version of node(16.x) while this project has an outdated(14.x) version of node. npm update does not work either, any suggestions how can i run this project?
here's the log file for 'npm install'

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.15.0
2 info using node@v16.17.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\FYP\Project Frontend\fyp\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
22 verbose title npm install
23 verbose argv "install"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
28 verbose logfile C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-12T16_19_59_564Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 36ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1762ms
37 warn old lockfile
37 warn old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
37 warn old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
37 warn old lockfile
37 warn old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
37 warn old lockfile
```

And here's the error

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.17.1', npm: '8.15.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated @types/classnames@2.3.1: This is a stub types definition. classnames provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated mini-create-react-context@0.4.1: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated redux-devtools-extension@2.13.9: Package moved to @redux-devtools/extension.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
```

Comment: Well, you can do 1 of 2 options.
Option 1: downgrade your node to 14.x and then try to run
Option 2: delete the package-lock.json from the root of the project

both have their consequences though.

Comment: @Daniyal did you check my answer ?

Comment: @NasirRabbani i tried deleting package-lock.json from the project and then tried npm insatll but is still giving various dependencies errors

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 (Recommended)**

I suggest that to use a tool for switching versions of node and npm called `nvm`. By the way, you don't have to upgrade/downgrade whole project dependencies. It is a minimal solution and it will work on further projects.

To install nvm check the *table of contents* section in [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

After installation of `nvm`:

---

**Step 1**

*Installing desired node version*

`nvm install v14.18.0`

---

*Also you can check supported versions by this command*

`nvm ls-remote`

---

**Step2**

*Switching version*

`nvm use v14.18.0`

---

**Step 3**

`npm install`

---

**Solution 2**

It is more painful because you must repeat each project's steps.

- Downgrade your node version to "14.x.x"
- Delete the package-lock.json (because you installed it for the new version of the node)
- And install dependencies.
- And repeat these steps for different versioned projects.

Comment: Hi batuhan, i tried to go through these steps but i got know nvm is not fully supported by windows it has some alternatives etc so what's your suggestion? I've been thinking of going to linux for some time and guess the time is now

Comment: I am using `nvm` on windows. Check it out https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Batuhan's answer, and I would like to add some supplementary information regarding this question for those who are seeking to install npm dependencies for older projects.

When the terminal displays the following message, it indicates that the current npm version being used on your device does not match the npm version required by the package-lock.json file.

```
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
```

You can check the 'lockfileversion' in your package-lock.json file and then determine the correct npm version that is required. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion

Next, you can verify the compatible Node.js version and install it using nvm.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases